# Set autolayout constraints accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

In my app i have a `UIView` i use as a container. It changes its height depending on if shown on a 3.5 inch or a 4 inch screen. I has 4 subviews as shown on the image.
What i want is to have these 4 subviews to have no space between each other and have the same height regardless what height is the view that contains them.

It looks good on this 4 inch screen:

[image]

But it looks bad on this 3.5 inch screen:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Zoli

Answer (score 0):

Just add a constrain to the height of the view, it will keep the height static:

[image]

Ctrl+click on the top part of the view, go down a bit and release the click, you'll se the option.

Comment: command click only selects/deselects the view for me. note i use a touchpad

Comment: oh i see! But this pins the height to a constant. i would like the heights to be changed to always fill their superview equally